# Missing fields on my contact page layout when I go to lightning

Tags: lightning

When I use classic I am able to log call and activities on my contact page, however, when I switch to lightning, I don't have the same fields. I am unable to add any new activities on my contact page, I can see the past activities but can't add new. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

In Lightning Experience, the details in those lists are surfaced in a more intelligent way in the activity timeline.

[image]

You can add the Activities Component by using Lightning App Builder. Go to your contact page and edit the page by clicking the setup icon available and click on edit page option. Drag the Activities component from the standard component from left-hand side pane. Once done, save it and activate it.

If you are not able to see Email, New Task, Log a Call, New Event options, you need to add those section in mobile and Lightning experience section on the page layout and add those actions to this section.

[image]

Read my Blog on Activities:- [Open Activities and Activity History Related List in Lightning Experience](https://salesforcediaries.com/2019/02/04/open-activities-and-activity-history-related-list-in-lightning-experience/)

Reference:- [Add Send an Email, Log a Call, New Event, and New Task Buttons to the Activity Composer](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=activitytimeline_configure_call_task_event_tabs.htm&type=5)